# Finding id inside array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to find an object inside array of objects.

```
secondary_todo.secondary.findOne({_id:fields.secondaryRefid}, function (err, tertiary_todo) {.........}
```

> TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'findOne .

What I need to do to get the object by its id?

Answer (score 0):

If `secondary` is an array of sub-documents, you can try with:

secondary_todo.findOne({'secondary._id': fields.secondaryRefid}, function (err, tertiary_todo) {.........});

Also, if you want to show only the matched subdocument you can use [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in projection (i.e. `{`secundary.$': 1}).

Comment: hi Dario , I tried your suggestion it throws an error
  " has no method 'findOne' "

Comment: secondary_todo is your collection object or mongoose model?

Comment: secondary_todo is my collection object

Comment: can you update your code, adding how you get this object? Both [collection native mondodb object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne) and Mongoose model have `findOne` method.